# Tabs in right and left side of TabControl c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have tabs in both sides of TabControl ?
if yes how can i do it ?

Comment: did u get them on the left side first? well +1 for the your requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the alignment of all of the tabs on the control *(top, left, right, bottom)* but you cannot split them apart so that 2 tabs are on the left side and 2 tabs are on the right side.

*I'm not sure if I've ever even seen a third party tab control that can do this.*