# Is it possible to draw a single TabPage aligned right and the rest left?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm unable to find anybody even mention this, which i find a bit odd, if this is possible could somebody point me in the right direction please.

I'm aware this is obviously far from standard but i was sort of hoping there might be something already floating around. I probably won't bother if that's not the case, i might perhaps opt for a work around, like a button/panel combo.

**UPDATE:** I'm referring to the TabControl's item spacing at the top, not the TapPage itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which UI framework? Winforms or Wpf or..?

Comment: Winforms, and that does not work alykins.

Comment: Sorry i should of specified that i do mean the TabControl's item spacing at the top, not the page itself, i'll update my question to save confusion.

Comment: So do you mean the spacing between the selection icons for each tab? like the little tab portion you would click on to navigate to a certain tab? And by that I mean have Tab1 link be on the left, and then Tab2 link be on the right?

Comment: Ah, for that it would appear the answer is no. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745313/tabs-in-right-and-left-side-of-tabcontrol-c-sharp)

Comment: You can set the alignment using `TabControl.Alignment = TabAlignment.Right;` Are you referring to a panel of tabs where you want some aligned to the left and some to the right?

Comment: What behavior would you expect in the event that there are enough tabs open to fill the entire width of the control? I would think that would be problematic to account for in your vision for tab page alignment.

Comment: The typical tab item scroll icons to appear at the right of the left aligned items, followed by a small spacing, and then the right aligned tabs.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah I think your idea of using a button in addition to another control is prob the best bet.  Good luck.